# Verilog: if else to Casex conversion

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, case, verilog

```
reg A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;
always@(*)
if (A) H = F & G;
else if (B) H = F | G;
else if (C) H = F ^ G;
else H = D & E;
```

I have to replace these statements with a casex statement. Can someone help me with the code

My code is this which is wrong ....

```
reg A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;
always@(*)
begin
casex(A or B or C or D or E or F or G or H)
A: H= F & G;
B: H = F | G;
C: H = F ^ G;
default: H = D & E;
endcase
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `A or B or C` is syntactically wrong and logical intention is also incorrect, so it does not work. So, you need to use something like the following:

```
reg A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;
always@(*)
begin
  casex(1'b1)
   A: H= F & G;
   B: H = F | G;
   C: H = F ^ G;
   default: H = D & E;
  endcase
end
```

The code in the original post represent a mux. A standard way to express it using a 'case' statement is shown above. The code means that if any of the variables 'A', 'B' or 'C' become '1' , the corresponding statement will be executed in simulation.